# Is it always possible for validation accuracy to be as high as training accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have a very small dataset (40 training examples, 10 validation examples, 120 classes) for which I'm getting very high accuracies with a very simple model in Keras (batchnorm, flatten, and dense layers only).

My training accuracy is 94-95% and validation accuracy is 76-78%. I know it's overfitting and I have tried a few things. The data is not images, so I cannot augment the data. I also cannot add data because it's a specific type. I'm using two dropout layers with 0.5 levels, and the architecture is very simple so I don't think I can reduce the architecture complexity. I can paste the model if anyone likes.

My question is: Is there ever a situation where validation accuracy cannot be as high as the training accuracy? Is there a limitation based on the size of the dataset? Or is it ALWAYS possible for validation accuracies to match training accuracies and the network just needs the right parameters?

Thank you so much

Comment: Voted to close, you are better off asking on stats.stackexchange or the data science site. To answer your question, yes it is possible but highly unlikely. For example, in the scenario where your test set is an exact copy of your trianing set. More generally, if you have indeed discovered the true data generation process, then you should get the "same" training and validation accuracy.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I will post it there.

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly overfitting.

Overfitting doesn't happen only because of "too powerful models", but also, and a lot, because of not enough data, and I'm quite convinced it's your case.

40 examples for 120 classes? That sounds really like a lot of data is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.